# Enlazar controles de usuario en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

He desarrollado un control de usuario en WPF en donde uno de los controles es un text box el cual en mi control de usuario lo declaro de la siguiente forma:

```
<TextBox Name="PathTextBox" Text="{Binding PathControlValue, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" Grid.Column="0" />
```

En el code behind tengo declarado lo siguiente:

```
public string PathControlValue
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(PathValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PathValueProperty, value); }
        }
```

Junto con:

```
 public static DependencyProperty PathValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "PathControlValue",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(FolderChoosed), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Al momento de usar mi control de usuario en un Window de wpf lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
<customUserControl:FolderChoosed Grid.Column="0" LabelControlValue="Banco anexo" Margin="10"
                                                         x:Name="BancoAnexo" Grid.Row="0"
                                                         ToolTipControlTitleValue="Banco anexo"
                                                         ToolTipControlDescriptionValue="Proporciona la ruta de los anexos"
                                                         PathControlValue="{Binding CompanyMapperDto.BancoAnexoPath, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Cuando Se inicializa mi window realizo lo siguiente:

```
InitializeComponent();
            _parameterService = IsnContainer.Resolve<IParameterService>();
            _dataBaseProviderService = IsnContainer.Resolve<IDataBaseProviderService>();
            DataContext = this;
```

Evidentemente tengo mi Window declarado de la siguiente forma:

```
public partial class CompanyMapper : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Y la propiedad que enlaza mi control de usuario es:

```
 private CompanyMapperDto _companyMapperDto;

        public CompanyMapperDto CompanyMapperDto
        {
            get { return _companyMapperDto; }
            set
            {
                _companyMapperDto = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CompanyMapperDto));
            }
        }
```

Aun asi la caja de texto de mi control de usuario no enlaza la informacion como deberia esperarse, pues una vez se carga mi objeto el control de usuario en su textBox sigue estando vacio ...

Alguna sugerencia

Comment: no hay ningun error reportado de binding en la consola no?

Comment: @gbianchi Nop, ninguno

Comment: Cambia `{ Binding ...}` por `{TemplateBinding PathControlValue}` y dejame saber.